# AWS config with local endpoint environment variable to use with 3rd party tools like MinIO

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sam, minio

I am running MinIO docker instance in my local environment for testing(integration) my SAM(Lambda) application.

MinIO gives all the standard AWS S3 facility locally. And it can be connected locally as following

```golang
    awsSession := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(true),

        // TODO: In production this should be picked automatically as per the region
        Endpoint:   aws.String("host.docker.internal:9000"),
        DisableSSL: aws.Bool(true),
    }))
```

I want to find out if there is an `environment variable` which can be used by config to pick endpoint? Hence, in my case I should be able to set the environment variable to `host.docker.internal:9000`.